# Count the 'F' status between two 'P' statuses

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of statuses in a table in sql server. I want to count the 'F' status between two 'p' statuses.If 'p' status is found, the count should be zero.
Let me give an example

```
Status
P
F
F
P
F
F
P
```

Expected Output:-

```
Status  Count
P       0
F       1
F       2
P       0
F       1
F       2
P       0
```

Is it somehow possible??

Comment: Rows in a database don't have an intrinsic order. To be able to do this reliably, you need an ID or created date or similar which could be referenced in an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee that the records come out as you're expecting.

Comment: Do you have a column which can gtd the sequence?  For example and Identity or Effective date?

Comment: yes rownumber is unique id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming* that you have an ID column, then you can use a windowed count to create groups, and the `ROW_NUMBER` to get the results you want. if you donj't have an ID, you'll need to implement one to get what you're after:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           [Status],
           COUNT(CASE [Status] WHEN 'P' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(1,'P'),
                (2,'F'),
                (3,'F'),
                (4,'P'),
                (5,'F'),
                (6,'F'),
                (7,'P'))V(ID,[Status]))
SELECT ID,
       [Status],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID) -1 AS [Count]
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: If it answers the question, @MS , please mark is as the solution, so that future readers know the answer was helpful. Thanks.